# Functions are used as variables, how to know which function is actually called using their memory address

Tags: c, visual-studio, function, memory

I'm working with a set of functions, having the same signature, saying

```
typedef int(*function_type)(int a, int b)
```

All those functions (lots of them) get stored in action_list arrays.
Further in in the program the following things happen:

```
chapter->action = (function_type)action_list[i];
...
chapter->action(x, y);
```

What I'd like to know, is which exact function is called by that last line, which is easy: I just use the debugger, put a breakpoint on that line, press F11 (step into) and I see it.

Problem: that line `chapter->action(x, y);` exists on many places within my code, and I'm interested in the complete list of those called functions.
Obviously I could search for all functions having the same signature and add a `print([%s], __FUNCTION__)` at the beginning of those, but as I'm talking here about a computer program of some millions of lines of source code, that's also not an option neither.

I've already tried:

```
printf("[%s]\n", chapter->action);
```

But this was a bad idea :-). The following was better, but now I'm stuck:

```
printf("[%p]\n", chapter->action);
```

Now I know where in memory these function are stored (I have the complete list), but how can I use these values to know which functions I'm dealing with? (I've already checked, while re-running the program, the same pointer values seem to be used)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680578(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Why is there a cast? `(function_type)` This means that something is fishy in your code.

Comment: Anyway, it would seem you are looking to generate a map file, that lists which addresses that all your functions are allocated at. How to do that in VS, I don't know.

Comment: Are you able to add code to where you're populating the action_list?

Comment: @ChrisTurner: No, this is not possible, there are too much of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are under the Windows environment and are using Visual studio, I can suggest a simple method. What you can do is generate a DLL instead of an executable with all the functions exported. 
A simple wrapper program can then call the main function inside the dll.
You can get a list of all the addresses that were called. Finally you can use [SymFromAddr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681323(v=vs.85).aspx) to get a string name of the function.

Seems like a long way, but right now that is all I can think of, if you want to avoid parsing the pdb. There are also some open source tools available that can help you with the pdb file. So you could use those too.

Comment: The program I'm working on is a DLL and I'm indeed working on a Windows platform. Excuse my ignorance, but how can I use this `SysFromAddr` function? I've just tried the following and it does not work: `rundll32 C:\windows\System32\DbgHelp.dll,SymFromAddr <product>.dll`.

Comment: You will have to call the SymFromAddr function from inside your dll. Where you get the address of the function (ie chapter->action), you can make the call to get the name.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680578(v=vs.85).aspx This specified by @StoryTeller above has example on how to use it.

Comment: You will have to write GetCurrentProcess() in place of hProcess because you want to search for the symbol in the current process.